# iis express from vs error ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express, visual-studio-2022

Running an MVC project in VS 2022, .NET Framework 4.8.  When I run from VS, I get the below error.  This was working as of a couple days ago, suddenly I get this error.  I am inexperienced in all things IIS Express, how can I go about troubleshooting this exception?  Google search has not turned up anything helpful to me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

EDIT:  I created a new ASP.NET MVC application and was able to run it in IIS Express without issue.  It is running under a different port (https://localhost:44327/) that the project I'm having issues with.  I tried changing the port# on the problem project, but still get the same error.

In doing all of this, my applicationhost.config for IIS Express didn't change at all.

Comment: Not a surprise if your Windows HTTP API certificate mappings have been changed by something, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling IIS Express in Visual Studio Installer, rebooting, and reinstalling IIS Express (along with all dependent components that had been removed) fixed my issue.